# Magento: is there a way to display related products with visibility set to 'Catalog' on frontend?

Tags: php, magento

Unlike 'Upsells' on the product view page, 'related products' block does not display products with visibility set to 'Catalog'.

It would be helpful to know if there a way to display related products with visibility set to 'Catalog' on frontend?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just had the same issue.

Fix is to comment out the following line in the file **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Related.php**:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
```